# Topologically equivalent metrics? Ceiling function of metric $d$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I am asked if the following metrics are topologically equivalent or not.

> $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $d$ is the metric. Define $\lceil{d} \rceil (x,y)$ := $\lceil{d(x,y)} \rceil$:$X \times X \rightarrow [0, \infty)$. Are $d$ and $\lceil{d} \rceil$ topologically equivalent?
>   Give a proof if so, or provide a counter example.

My attempt was to say we have some sequence ${x_n}$ that converges to some $x$. Then, I managed to say that if $d(x_n,x) \rightarrow 0$ then $\lceil{d(x,y)} \rceil \rightarrow 0$ so I have that bit okay(If my tactics are okay).

I am having trouble with showing the reverse; $\lceil{d(x,y)} \rceil \rightarrow 0$ implies $d(x_n,x) \rightarrow 0$.

Well, because $\lceil{d(x,y)} \rceil =0$ simply means that $x \in (-1,0]$ yes?
So it does not necessarily mean it converges to $0$.

So I thought this means that they are "inequivalent" i.e. a counterproof but I cannot be sure if this works or qualifies as a counterproof...I mean, while I cannot guarantee it is $0$, I also have no means to say that it can never be $0$.

I guess I am basically stuck.
What should I do? Can someone please help me out? Thank you so much for your help, very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

HINT: If $x,y\in X$, and $x\ne y$, then $\lceil d\rceil(x,y)\ge 1$, $\{x\}$ is always open (why?). Is this necessarily true in $\langle X,d\rangle$?

Comment: Hi, I may be quite flimsy now on analysis theory but, ${x}$ is a single element set of the limit of ${x_n}$? And it is an open set...? I'm sorry,  still can't figure it out.. :/

Comment: @Melba1993: There’s no reason to look at sequences at all. Show that if $0<r\le 1$, $B_{\lceil d\rceil}(x,r)=\{x\}$, so that $\{x\}$ is an open set. Then take $\langle X,d\rangle$ to be, for example, $\Bbb R$ with the usual metric; in that space is it *ever* true that $\{x\}$ is an open set?

Comment: Okay....right, again, maybe I am being very wobbly, but $B_{\lceil{d} \rceil}(x,r)=\{x\}$ an open ball? I mean, I know open balls are always open and closed balls are always closed so if it is an open ball, then it's immediate that it is open..which feels like I am not solving anything, so how is $B_{\lceil{d} \rceil}(x,r)$ defined? Say,$B_{\lceil{d} \rceil}(x,r)=\{y \in X | \lceil{d} \rceil(x,y) < r\}$ (which is, well, the open ball)? Or am I misunderstanding something :/ For the latter bit, I am guessing the answers is "no" because it is not restricted to $\mathbb{Z}$ but I am not sure...

Comment: @Melba1993: Your understanding of $B_{\lceil d\rceil}(x,r)$ is correct. And if $r\le 1$, the only $y\in X$ such that $\lceil d\rceil(x,y)<r$ is $x$ itself, so in that case $B_{\lceil d\rceil}(x,r)=\{x\}$: in the space $\langle X,\lceil d\rceil\rangle$, $\{x\}$ **is** the open ball of radius $r$ centred at $x$. Now if $X=\Bbb R$, and $d$ is the usual metric on $\Bbb R$, is the set $\{x\}$ ever an open set?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider the interval $[0,1]$ with the usual metric. What is the topology under the ceiling metric?

Comment: Hi, so the usual metric under ceiling would be...always $+1$ I guess? Because the distance between any 2 distinct points in the interval will be greater than 0 less than 1 and the ceiling would give it $+1$....

Comment: Yes, if $x\ne y$ the new distance between $x$ and $y$ is $1$. Then if $x$ is any point, then the set of points with new distance less than $1$ from $x$ is open. But this is just the point $x$, so all one point sets are open. That is certainly not true of the usual topology on $[0,1]$. So the topologies are not equivalent.